# typeerror unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, int, typeerror

Here's the code:

```
list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
list2 = [range(list[-1], 2000000)]
y =11
x = 1
v = list[-1]>= x
while list[-1] ** 2 < 2000000:
    y= y + 2
    prime = True
    while prime == True:    
        for x in list:
            if x * 2 < y:   
                if y % x == 0:
                    prime = False
                    break
        if prime == True:
            list.append(y)
            prime = False
print sum(list)

for u in list:
    for w in list2:
        if u * u < w:
            if w % u == 0:
                list2.pop(w)
print list
print sum(list) + sum(list2)
```

As you see, it's a basic program that creates a sieve and then puts numbers up to two million for it. It's for project Euler and I'm trying to test my skills as I learn to program.

Right now, the error, for which this post is titled is on line 23. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: I removed a large chunk of your post to just focus on the question itself. For help with Stack Overflow itself, please ask on http://meta.stackoverflow.com instead. On formatting, see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for example.

Comment: Python programming remark: Don't name a variable `list`, there already is a built-in type `list` that you've now shadowed.

Comment: Your comments are awesome and helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`range()` already returns a list, but you put it into a new list:

```
list2 = [range(list[-1], 2000000)]
```

This results in a list containing a list, and `w` later on is set to the full range. Just remove the brackets there.

```
>>> [range(5)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @goldenparrot: the OP (in the long version of the post) stated they did their best with formatting, but that's a common posting error and not necessarily anything in the original code. There would have been a syntax error in that case.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted the answer. I'd vote it up but I don't have the reputation for it.